# NBFM and WBFM power spectral density

Tags: power-spectral-density, frequency-modulation

The  power density of a general FM modulated signal(with modulation index close to 1) looks like this:

[image]

By picking out the carrier frequency we can make the FM signal narrowband or wideband.Now obviously when we changed the carrier frequency , the power of the FM signal wouldnt change so the smaller the bandwidth the more power is distributed evenly among the frequencies and the bigger the bandwidth the more power is near the carrier frequency.Is this correct?

Comment: No -- your definition of "narrowband" vs "wideband" seems to be relative to the carrier frequency, but the spectrum itself (and thus the power distribution) does not depend on the carrier.

Comment: Please _edit and adjust your question_ so that you are using the term "modulation index" correctly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation#Modulation_index

Answer (score 1):

> the smaller the bandwidth the more power is distributed evenly among the frequencies and the bigger the bandwidth the more power is near the carrier frequency.Is this correct?

It's wrong, the opposite is true. I mean, the names *do* speak to their meaning: "wideband" distributes energy over a wide band, "narrow band" over a narrow band.

> By picking out the carrier frequency we can make the FM signal narrowband or wideband.

No. That's wrong; whether we call something "wideband FM" or "narrowband FM" depends on the modulation index. The carrier frequency has nothing to do with it. The modulation index is an indication how much wider the bandwidth of the FM signal becomes when you increase the message signal bandwidth.

Different authors use wildly different thresholds for the modulation index regarding when to call things NB or WB¹; you will have to decide to pick any number and go with that. The American Radio Relay League, in contradiction to all sources I could find, defines it using fixed bandwidth limit in its "*The ARRL Handbook*", 8th ed. They use 3 kHz as bandwidth limit – a pretty low boundary, but understandable, as they'd limit themselves to voice, which one can cut off at ca 3 kHz (audio frequency) without losing too much intelligebility². Contrasting that, *Digital and analog communcation systems* 4th ed by Leon W. Couch defines NB to be anything $\beta \le 0.2$ ($\beta$ being the modulation index); I had to dig up a rather old text book to even find one that deals with that!

---

<sup>¹ for example, the wikipedia article on *Frequency Modulation* contradicts itself within one paragraph, so be very careful about material that might be written by people who learned from wikipedia. This problem is exacerbated by the fact that analog FM is an old technology, as it's not close to optimal for any use case I can think of. It is historically important, which is why it's used in audio broadcast all over the world, and it's been an upgrade to understandability for voice comms, which is why amateur radio enthusiasts still use it, but there's simply no need to design new FM systems, which is why the categorization into two categories "WB" and "NB" serves no significant purpose. An engineer tasked with building a modulator or demodulator for FM in 2024 will ask for a specification for the modulation index, as a cold hard number, not for a human term like "narrowband FM, you know!".</sup>

<sup>² As expected from the ARRL, they don't really state how they define bandwidth; of course, if one follows logic or Carson's bandwidth rule, a FM modulation with bandwidth 3 kHz and a voice bandwidth of 3 kHz can't exist, so one is left to wonder how harshly an NBFM transmitter according to the ARRL definition cuts off the voice frequencies on the upper end; can't go much below 2.75 kHz (and that would already have a bit more than 3 kHz bandwidth at $\beta=0.1$, which is pretty much as low as FM modulation indices go), or even deep male voice becomes hard to understand, especially in the consonants; forget about large percentiles of female voices. I'm packing a bit of snark but also carry a bit of sadness when I say that: one of the effects of having a gender-wise unbalanced field like amateur radio, is that such definitions make it into publications, regulations and standards.</sup>